# SQL database being updated with HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql

OK, I have been trying to fool around with getting SQL to add a 1 to a specific row/table.

Say like you do this type of form and it makes a certain value go to 1 so you can't do it again. It's like that.

```
<input name="something" type="hidden" class="buttonsmall" id="something" size="100" maxlength="100" value="<?php  SELECT FROM  `table` WHERE  `table`.`int' SET == 1;?>"/>
```

Sample code of it. I just can't get it to put the variable as a 1.

Pretty new to SQL and PHP so don't know that much with HTML forms and them updating the database..

Need any more information just ask.

Comment: well.... its time to buy a book on php basics may be?

Comment: You can't just execute SQL in PHP. You need to use the `PDO` class and use that to get the information. Also, `==` is not in SQL - you need to use a single `=` sign.

Comment: O'Reilly has the eponymous Wine Store App book that's been around for a decade by now. Get one, sit down with it, and go through it. It's thick, it's dated, but at least you'll get the idea. They're also plentiful and cheap.

Comment: Learning basic of SQL & PHP may help you..

Comment: I know the basics. I just needed to figure this out and since no one appears to have enough information or just doesn't feel like helping I see no point anymore. Been looking this up for the longest now, found this site multiple times on things that didn't answer the question so I just asked myself.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how SQL works in PHP.

Start by reading about [database access with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and go from there.  When you have read that, and have executed some SQL queries through PHP, and you got a program that isn't quite working, come back to us.

As it stands now, for us to help fix that code, we would have to teach you about PHP and database from scratch, and that makes no sense when the docs do a fine job of that already.

Comment: I already have executed SQL queries through PHP I just need to figure out how to add a 1 to the SQL database through PHP...

Answer (score 0):

PHP and SQL are different languages.

You are running a SQL statement inside a PHP document.

The reason this can't work is PHP has no idea about how to connect to a database. It has no idea what a database is. PHP is used for manipulating data and sending it to the front-end.

A database can be accessed via SQL, a language that was built solely for that purpose.

Now the line you've written is a pure SQL line and hence PHP can't understand or do anything with it.

To learn how to execute SQL in PHP you have to show PHP how to access your DB which is done via a class called `PHP Data Objects` or `PDO`

Likely to find more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I have it so it connects to the database and among other things.

Comment: Variable as  a 1. .  Which variable??? Your SQL is just a sentence and has no PHP variable in it.. PHP variables have a $ preface